# Avoid overridding of default message field in logstash

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using logstash to parse my logs. when i am parsing the json (which contains a "message" field) overrides the default message field. I tried using remove_field option of json{ } filter but that didn't work work for me.

Here is my filter code:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message", "\"", "'"]
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message", ".", "_"]
    }
    csv {
        columns => ["TIMESTAMP", "HEADERS", "FIELD1", "FIELD2", "FIELD2_TIME", "INTER_FIELD2"]
        separator => "|"
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["FIELD1", "'", '"']
    }

  #Removing message field inside FIELD1 json to avoid overriding
    json {
        source => "FIELD1"
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["FIELD2", "'", '"']
    }
    json {
        source => "FIELD2"
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
}
```

How to avoid overriding of the defaultmessage field ?

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

1. move the [message] field out of the way before calling the json{} filter (mutate->rename).
2. use the 'target' param of the json{} filter to put the json data somewhere other than the root of the document.